# Android tab layout without swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

Since the `Tabhost` is deprecated by android, an suggest way to implement tab is to use fragment and pager. However, pager is introducing "swipe-able" views.

I am designing to implement an application. It uses tabs with multiple pages, and also has navigation drawer when swipe from edge. 

I think both navigation drawer and pagers are swipe-able will introduce some trouble when users using it (i.e. user swipe left to right trying to show navigation drawer, but page changes instead). I want to make the pagers to be non-swipe-able in this case.

Is there a way to do it? or should I not use pager in this case? What will be a good resolution to this issue?

Comment: Have you tried it? There are lots of apps that use both View Pagers and the Navigation Drawer and they work just fine.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing ActionBar?

Answer (score 1):

Use View Pager 
it can be done with out any issues , we can set the space up to which navigation drawer can take action